# If get inorder successor in BST takes O(h), why does iterative inorder traversal take O(n) when calling an O(h) function n times?

Tags: binary-search-tree

In a BST, it takes O(h) time complexity to get the inorder successor of a given node, so given getNext(), which gets the inorder successor of the current node, you would need n calls to getNext() to traverse the tree, giving O(nh) time complexity.

However, iterative inorder traversal of BST's are given in books to take O(n) time.  I'm confused why there's a difference.

(Nodes have parent pointers).

Comment: When you find the inorder successor of a BST, you look for the smallest element greater than the input node. So, in a BST you would only have to look for either the elements in the right subtree or the parents of the element. So, in case of skewed trees you'd have to traverse the from bottom to top which will be O(h). Whereas in a traversal, you have to visit every node of a BST so the complexity will be O(n)

Comment: If you're doing inorder traversal (without recursion), you still have to find the inorder successor for the current node, so where would be the difference?

Comment: Can you give the (steps or code of the) specific algorithm you’re trying to find the time complexity of? It’ll help with the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the inorder successor is O(h), but not Ө(h). Half of the nodes will have a successor just one link away. Let’s think about the number of pointer dereferences it takes to traverse a given node:

- the number of pointer dereferences to traverse the left subtree, plus
- the number to ascend back from the left subtree’s rightmost node = the height of the left subtree (at most), plus
- one for the node itself, plus
- the number to descend to the right subtree’s rightmost node = the height of the right subtree (at most), plus
- the number for the right subtree.

So an upper bound is:

f(0) = 1
f(h) = f(h − 1) + (h − 1) + h + (h − 1) + f(h − 1)
    
 = 2f(h − 1) + 3h − 2

f(h) = 5·2<sup>h</sup> − 3h − 4

and h being ⌈log₂ n⌉, f is O(n).